# Horizontally centering Font Awesome icon and text

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

I have a regular line of text centered horizontally.  But I cannot get a font awesome icon to sit to the left of this centered text.

Any CSS rule I use for alignment, places the icon to the far left and the text centered.

I am using the Avada theme for WordPress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: and what version of font awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the icon and the text in a p element, then center the p.

See this [Pen](https://codepen.io/aureliendebord/pen/dKGoaL).

**html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <p><i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> Icon text</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container p {
  text-align: center;
}
```